# How to obtain bean's @Qualifier value from BeanDefinition

Tags: spring

I wonder if there is a way to learn a bean's `@Qualifier` value (if any) from a `BeanDefinition`. Although qualifier is an important attribute of a bean, I don't see appropriate methods on the BeanDefinition interface or any of its inheritors.

Comment: Beans don't have a qualifier value; they have names.  `@Qualifier` is used to guide Spring on which bean to inject when multiple beans of the same type are available, it does not add attributes to the bean.  If you want to get the bean name at runtime, implement `BeanNameAware` on your beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `BeanDefinition` is in the type of `AnnotatedBeanDefinition` , you can cast to it and play around its `getMetadata()` or `getFactoryMethodMetadata()` to obtain its annotation related data.

For example , if the bean is defined in the traditional way such as :

```java
@Component
@Qualifier("foo")
public class FooBean  {

}
```

Then :

```java
AnnotationMetadata annoMetadata = annotatedBeanDefinition.getMetadata();
MethodMetadata beanMethodMetadata = annotatedBeanDefinition.getFactoryMethodMetadata(); //NULL as this bean is not defined by the @Bean factory method
Map<String, Object> qualifierAttribute = annoMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(Qualifier.class.getName());
```

will give you an attribute map for the `@Qualifier` on this bean which has the the value `{value=foo}`

On the other hand , if the bean is defined via `@Bean` method such as :

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {
    
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("bar")
    public BarBean barBean(){
    }
}
```

Then :

```java
AnnotationMetadata annoMetadata = annotatedBeanDefinition.getMetadata();  //return the AnnotationMetadata on Config class only. Not the thing we are look at
MethodMetadata beanMethodMetadata = annotatedBeanDefinition.getFactoryMethodMetadata(); 
Map<String, Object> qualifierAttribute = beanMethodMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(Qualifier.class.getName());
```

will give you an attribute map for the `@Qualifier` which is  `{value=bar}`

If the bean is defined without any `@Qualifier` , then `qualifierAttribute` map will be null.